# DBCP Connection Pool leak : Connection.close() don't return the Connection to the pool and the connection is exhausted

Tags: mysql, jdbc, connection, connection-pooling

DBCP connection pool leak .

When the program return the connection used, the connection resource is not returned to 
 the pool and is exhausted !!!

So, in maxActive time Connection.close(), the pool hangs when getConnection().

Please let me know how to solve this problem !!!

library :

commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
commons-pool-1.6.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.12.jar

Mysql version : 5.5.9

Sources :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;



class ConnectionManager {

    static {

        java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver((java.sql.Driver) 
                  Class.forName("org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDriver").newInstance()) ;
        java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver((java.sql.Driver) 
                  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()) ;
   }

   public Connection getConnection(String dataSourceName) {

       return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:apache:commons:dbcp:/"+dataSourceName);
   }

}
```

query source ::

```
String dsName = "pool" ;

ConnectionManager pool = new ConnectionManager();

java.sql.Connection conn = pool.getConnection(dsName);


conn.setAutoCommit(true);
if( m_sql.trim().toUpperCase().startsWith("INSERT") )
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(m_sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
else
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(m_sql);

pstmt.setFetchSize(100);

boolean hasRS = pstmt.execute();

ResultSet resSet = null ;

if (hasRS) {
   resSet = pstmt.getResultSet();

} else {
   resSet = null;
   return ;
}

while(resSet.next()) {

     //resultSet processing ....
     ::::::
}


resSet.close() ;
pstmt.close() ;
conn.close() ;  --> don't return the connection to the pool and exhaust the connection...;;;
```

:::

poo.jocl  :: this is located in $CLASSPATH

```
<object class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory">
    <string value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useUnicode=true&amp;traceProtocol=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
    <string value="usera"/>
    <string value="passa"/>
</object>

<object class="org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool">
    <object class="org.apache.commons.pool.PoolableObjectFactory" null="true" />
    <int value="100" /> <!-- maxActive -->
            <byte value="1" /> <!-- whenExhaustedAction -->
    <long value="10000" /> <!-- maxWait -->
    <int value="30" /> <!-- maxIdle -->
    <int value="3" />  <!-- minIdle -->
    <boolean value="true" /> <!-- testOnBorrow -->
    <boolean value="true" />  <!--testOnReturn -->
    <long value="600000" />  <!-- timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis -->
    <int value="5" />  <!-- numTestsPerEvictionRun -->
    <long value="3600000" /> <!-- minEvictableIdleTimeMillis -->
    <boolean value="true" /> <!-- testWhileIdle -->
</object>

<object class="org.apache.commons.pool.KeyedObjectPoolFactory" null="true"/>    
<string null="true"/>   
<boolean value="false"/>
<boolean value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably aren't using the Apache connection pool, because of registering the MySQL driver. Try removing that. You certainly haven't needed to register MySQL drivers at all since JDBC 4.0. In fact because of all the XML configuration I don't believe you need that static block at all. Try removing it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. MySQL driver don't need to be registered !!! But, removing that, the program also hangs...;;;

Comment: I don't know why the program use MySQL driver directly instead of Apache connection pool despite removing registering MySQL driver.

Comment: Ooooops!!!. I made a mistake in my project source...  The above source is ok. When I use a update query routine in my library. I missed close(). so foolish...;;;  Thank you for EJP. You're right. MySql driver is not needed to register. The staic routin is for not calling in getConnection() everytime !!!